# How to integrate a Wordpress blog in the navigation bar in a TYPO3 website

Tags: wordpress, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I am working a website that is built by using TYPO3. I am quite new to TYPO3, we want to integrate a nice looking blog with different categories in the website. Although there are a couple of blog exrensions that are provided from TYPO3 but a lot of customization that has to be done in the templates. Please donot recommend to use blog extension from TYPO3.

Ideally, we want to have a blog in Wordpress and integrate the link to this blog in our TYPO3 website. Blog will be a menu item in the top navigation bar in TYPO3 website, when a user clicks Blog he will be taken to a blog (done in Wordpress). Header and footer will remain same as we have in the website. Could some body please give any ideas that how it can be done like what changes I have to make in TYPO3 backend or in wordpress. Any helpful links or tutorials regarding how a wordpress page can be integrated in TYPO3 will also be super helpful. I already looked but was not really able to find any concrete info online.

Answer (score 0):

In general the question is just how to integrate a link to a foreign page or domain in the menu.

**The easiest approach** is to create a special page for the blog in the page-tree and choose the type

> Link to external URL

Like this you can create a common Menu and the link to the blog is automatically part of the menu. The advantage is that you also can count and track clicks on the link.

The screenshot is made in a very old version of TYPO3 but in general the important options in the form are still the same:

[image]

**Solution with TYPOScript**

While the common `HEMNU` in TypoScript is usually used to implement local pages inside the system, there exists a different option to include foreign links with `stdWrap.typolink`.

This approach is to create a `COA` where several content-elements can be defined including `HMENU` and also some text that is linked by `stdWrap.typolink` to foreign targets like the blog.

```
page.100 = COA
page.100 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    10 = HEMNU
    10 {
       ... [common pagemenu]
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20.value = Blog
    20.stdWrap.typolink.parameter = https://example.com
    20.stdWrap.typolink.extTarget = _blank
    20.wrap = <li>|</li>

    30 = HMENU
    30 {
       ... [another menu]
    }
}
```

Assumed you want the blog being opened in a new tab / window I added the line `20.stdWrap.typolink.extTarget = _blank`, just remove that line if it's not desired.

References:
 - [HMENU](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html)
 - [Menu Objects (sub-objects of `HMENU`)](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Index.html)
 - [typolink](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html)

Comment: Wouldn't adding an External URL page be easier?

Comment: Yes, right - I had a more academic approach in mind ;-)

Comment: @RudyGnodde I added your hint in the answer, thank's :-)

Comment: @David, Thanks a lot for the detailed and easy to understand explanation. I really appreciate the screenshot and Typoscript in your answer. One more thing that I would like to ask is that how can I have the same Header and Footer from my Typo3 website on this blog page now to  make this external link a part of the original  Typo3 website. Many thanks

Comment: Idea is that user clicks "Blog" and is taken to the external link but this link should have the same header and footer from the Typo3 website so that user can navigate to other pages.

Comment: Then either you've to work with iframe to be HTML5 compatible, use an older (X)HTML-standard to use frames or apply that same layout to your blog. The frame-solutions tend to be not responsive even it might be possible to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be menu, which contains parts from two CMSs.

if you only have fixed URLs which are from the non-TYPO3 system you can use pages of type 'external url' to build a menu with links outside of TYPO3.

for external systems we have used a special pagetype to render only the header or footer, so they can be used in the external system. I don't know how this can be done in wordpress.

if you have more than static page(s) of wordpress inside the TYPO3 menu you need a similar solution vice versa.